# Thumbnail for uploaded images

Tags: php, file-upload, thumbnails

i am using php tp upload images.... i was wondering

- how to create thumbnails of images ?
- how to customize their dimensions & proportions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using a class I found when I needed to do the same thing and so far, with few modifications it works great. Here you go: [SimpleImage Class](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php)

```
<?php
  include('SimpleImage.php');
  $image = new SimpleImage();
  $image->load('picture.jpg');
  $image->resize(250,400);
  $image->save('picture2.jpg');

  // and a lot more examples at the class website.
?>
```

If this does not suit your needs, php manual has lots of functions to help you achieving what you need. [Image](http://php.net/image)

Comment: this solution really saved me a lot of coding... hey do you know such a thing for Pagination... i am developing a dynamic Gallery

Comment: @Junaid, Glad it worked great for you. About pagination, usually I code that myself. But any simple google search should help you with that... Take a look at this: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/ and http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/perfect-php-pagination

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- [Resize/Thumbnail Images With PHP](http://www.vipercreations.com/tutorials/PHP/22.html)

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin that generates thumbnails with quality and size settings and clipping method, that caches the thumbnails, enabling you to use the same image in different places and sizes in your views.

I believe this may solve your problem:

https://github.com/emersonsoares/ThumbnailsPlugin

usage:

```
   echo $this->Thumbnail->render('test.jpg', array(
       'width' => '100',
       'height' => '100',
       'resizeOption' => 'portrait',
       'quality' => '100'
        ), array('id' => 'img-test', 'alt' => 'thumbnail test'));
```