# Upload image php mysql twice with different names

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, file-rename

I am **trying to upload an image** to the server (with a path in mysql table) **twice through php** with different names. One version of the image as "xxxx.png" and the other version of the image as "xxxxt.png".

**My php is:**

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['photo']) {
  $target = "images/properties/";  
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

  $pic = "images/properties/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (`productcode`, `photo`) VALUES ('$productcode', '$pic' )");
    echo "The new image has been added successfully"; 
  } else { 
    echo "Error uploading new image - please check the format and size"; 
  }
}

?>
```

The above code inserts the image into the mysql database and uploads the file to the server correctly.
I am however trying to upload the same image twice with a different naming convention on a "thumbnail" version. The slideshow script in my html only recognises the thumbnails if there are named with a "t" at the end of the filenames hence my problem.

I have been advised to look at the [php copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function to achieve this but am incredibly unclear as to how to incorporate such a function into my existing code.
Happy to provide the html or any other info if required.

Any help much appreciated. I did have another thread attempting to find out the same thing but I wasn't very clear!

Thanks
JD

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163642/thumbnail-for-uploaded-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've been advised you should use copy(). I didn't fully test this but give it a try:

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['photo'])
{
    $target = "images/properties/";

    $ext = array_pop(explode('.', $_FILES['photo']['name']));
    $copy = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name'], '.' . $ext) . 't.' . $ext;

    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $pic = "images/properties/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
        copy($target, $copy);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (`productcode`, `photo`) VALUES ('$productcode', '$pic' )");
        echo "The new image has been added successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error uploading new image - please check the format and size";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Better yet, you could use symlink() instead of copy() if the OS supports it. That would save disk space. The parameters would be the same I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand you, you do not need to upload this file twice. You already have this file on your server. So you should copy it (optionally do some transitions to make it more like a thumbnail) on your server's hard drive and update database.

Your code should like similar to this:

```
<?php 
if($_FILES['photo'])
{
  $target_dir = "images/properties/";

  $upload_file_name = basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
  $upload_file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $target_file = $target_dir . $upload_file_name . '.' . $upload_file_ext;
  $target_file_sql = $target_dir . mysql_real_escape_string($upload_file_name . '.' . $upload_file_ext);
  $target_thumb = $target_dir . $upload_file_name . 't.' . $upload_file_ext;
  $target_thumb_sql = $target_dir . mysql_real_escape_string($upload_file_name . 't.' . $upload_file_ext);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) 
  {  
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (`productcode`, `photo`) VALUES ('$productcode', '$target_file_sql' )");
    echo "The new image has been added successfully"; 

    if (copy($target_file, $target_thumb))
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (`productcode`, `photo`) VALUES ('$productcode', '$target_thumb_sql' )");
        echo "The new thumb image has been added successfully";
    } else 
    {
        echo "Error copying thumb file";
    }

  } else 
  { 
    echo "Error uploading new image - please check the format and size"; 
  }
}
```

Again, the idea is that you do not need to upload file twice in a row. All you need to do is just copy it on server.